# Extract part of the string if it contains word from the list of elements of another String Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I would like to extract the afterpart of a_string (abc@xyz.com) if any elements from msgs matches with a_string's content. Currently I am only able to search 1 element i.e.Email address: by hardcoding the search test with the below code but I want to compare more than one from msgs list. Can someone please help?

Please note it is multiline text from outlook mail and it can be **Email addresses:** or **Email address**

```
Mail delivery was not successful.
Delivery/update and destination information:
Run at: 5/12/2021 5:00:21 PM
Recipient name: John Doe
Email addresses: abc@xyz.com
Error message: Skipping content as no data returned.



  a_string = 'Error message: abc@xyz.com'
  msgs =['Email addresses: ', 'Email address: ']

  matches = re.finditer(r"Email address:\s(.*)$", a_string  re.MULTILINE)
  for match in matches:
      emailaddress=match.group(1)
      print(emailaddress)
```

Comment: You should consider doing `re.findall(f"{'|'.join(msgs)}(.*)", a_string)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
>>> import re
>>>
>>> a_string = """Mail delivery was not successful.
... Delivery/update and destination information:
... Run at: 5/12/2021 5:00:21 PM
... Recipient name: John Doe
... Email addresses: abc@xyz.com
... Error message: Skipping content as no data returned."""
>>> msgs = ['Email address:', 'Email addresses:']
>>> 
>>> p = rf"(?:{'|'.join(msgs)})\s(\S+)" 
>>> pat = re.compile(p)
>>> matches = pat.finditer(a_string, re.MULTILINE)
>>> 
>>> for match in matches:
...    print(match.group(1))
... 
abc@xyz.com
```

Note: `?:` makes the first group non-capturing and thus you can get the email address using `match.group(1)`. If you need which element of `msgs` matched together with an email address you can remove `?:`. Then, the email address will be at `match.group(2)` and `match.group(1)` will be element from `msgs`.

Comment: This is not working as i need to make sure i only get the line that has the word Email address in it. Sorry if i was not clear in my question.

Comment: I updated the answer. Are you looking for something like this? If not, can you please update your question with more details, including some representative sample of your input string and the expected output?

Comment: p = rf"(?:{'|'.join(matches)})\s(\S+)" 
            pat = re.compile(p)
            matches = pat.finditer(body,re.MULTILINE) # add re.MULTILINE if your string has multiple lines
            for match in matches:
                print(match.group(1)) .............. Tried this it still doesn't work

Comment: Works here w/ your input string. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `findall`:

```
import re
a_string = 'Error message: abc@xyz.com'
msgs =['Email addresses: ', 'Email address: ', 'Error message: ']

re.findall(fr"{'|'.join(msgs)}(.*)", a_string)
['abc@xyz.com']
```

Comment: This is not working as i need to make sure i only get the line that has the word Email address in it. Sorry if i was not clear in my question.

Comment: @user3438791 What exactly do you mean?

Comment: It is multiline paragraph, so the output that i got running the above code was a long list of double quotes.

Comment: Can you then update your question with a more realistic string that resembles what you have and also include the expected output

Comment: sure. Done that.

Comment: @user3438791 in that case, you could try `re.findall('Email address(?:es)?: (.*)', a_string)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232367/discussion-between-user3438791-and-onyambu).

Comment: There was post from another user as well with the below logic - p = rf"(?:{'|'.join(msgs)})\s(\S+)" 
pat = re.compile(p)
matches = pat.finditer(a_string, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    print(match.group(1))
This logic worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to thank another user who posted this answer.

```
p = rf"(?:{'|'.join(msgs)})\s(\S+)" 
pat = re.compile(p)
matches = pat.finditer(a_string, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Comment: It'd be great if you'd thank me by accepting and/or upvoting my answer if it resolved your issue :)

Comment: Thanks I upvoted it. Can you please also explain the logic?

Comment: Sure: a. create a pattern that will match any of the strings in `msgs` (read about `|` in `re`s docs) followed by a whitespace (`\s`), followed by one or more non-whitespace characters (`(\S+)`), b. compile the regex (see again `re`s docs), c. use `Pattern.finditer` against `a_string`, and d. print what matches `(\S+)`.